# Flash AS3 - Drag and Drop multiple objects to one target?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop

[image: example of what I'm aiming for]

Title is more or less self-explanatory, I’ve been working through many different tutorials and I’m not exactly too good with AS3 to be perfectly honest. (Image above shows what I'm aiming for)

Anyway, what I notice in most of the online tutorials I see, the drag and drop tutorials are either based on one object to one target or multiple objects to multiple targets, so I was wondering if someone is kind enough to help me and explaining how I can get multiple objects to connect to one target.

And, if possible making it switchable, as in for example, if object 1 is already in place on the target when I drag object 2 over, then object 1 returns to its original position and object two takes its place.

A easier way to explain this is to say that I'm trying to create a game where there are three statues and the user can pick one of the three to place in a set target zone.

I apologies if what I say doesn't make much sense, will clear up anything if that causes confusion. Here's the AS3 code I'm using at the moment.

```
var startX:int;
var startY:int;

circle1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
circle1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
circle2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
circle2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
circle3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
circle3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);

function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
    startX = event.target.x;
    startY = event.target.y;
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);

}

function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.stopDrag();

    var theTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
    var theTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(theTargetName);
    if (event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == theTarget){    
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = theTarget.x;
        event.target.y = theTarget.y;
    }

else{

    event.target.x = startX;
    event.target.y = startY;

circle1_mc.buttonMode = true;
circle2_mc.buttonMode = true;
circle3_mc.buttonMode = true;
```

Comment: You can put all of the statues in one array and have a `for each...in` statement check for all of them. Also, it's best if you just merge the two functions you have here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of checking the `dropTarget`, you can use `hitTestObject` to see if the dropped object is "touching" `theTarget`. Otherwise, any other item that has already been dropped onto `theTarget` may be reported as the `dropTarget`.
Also, since `MovieClip` is dynamic, you can store the `startX` and `startY` values in each instance.

The following modified code will use a single `target_mc` as a drop target. When one item is dropped on it, any other items will be moved back to their original spot:

```
// create an array as @David suggested to keep track of your draggable items
var circles:Array = [circle1_mc, circle2_mc, circle3_mc];
for each(var circleMC:MovieClip in circles)
{
    circleMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
    circleMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
    circleMC.startX = circleMC.x;
    circleMC.startY = circleMC.y;
}

function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // no longer need to keep track of startX & startY here because that's already been done up above
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);

}

function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
    // check to see if the event target is touching target_mc using hitTestObject
    if(event.target.hitTestObject(target_mc)){
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = target_mc.x;
        event.target.y = target_mc.y;
        // move all circles OTHER than the current target back to their original positions
        for each(var circleMC:MovieClip in circles)
        {
            if(event.target != circleMC)
            {
                circleMC.x = circleMC.startX;
                circleMC.y = circleMC.startY;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // only need to move the event target back if it was dropped outside of target_mc
        event.target.x = event.target.startX;
        event.target.y = event.target.startY;
        event.target.buttonMode = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a much more efficent way of going abouts with this! Thanks you so much! You and David! That's helped a lot more than I thought haha, sorry for the late reply though, I've been out for some time.