# Flash AS3 Dragging multiple objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

what I'm looking for is when I drag an object across the stage, I'd want an underlying object (same layer) to be dragged along, and remain where the primary object is placed. Would I need to use an array in the multiple objects situation?
This is just for one object (and 'sub-object'), there will be 22 of these in total, where I can't add the sub-object into its movieclip, else the other 21 objects on the stage will be overlapping and interfering with one another.

This is what I have so far, see illustration as well. Could anyone direct me to some useable code?

```
CF.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragCF);
CF.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, fadeCF_spaceIN);
CF.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fadeCF_spaceIN);

function dragCF(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    addChild(MovieClip(evt.currentTarget));
    evt.currentTarget.startDrag();
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropCF);   }   

function dropCF(evt:MouseEvent):void {
     stopDrag();
     stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropCF);  }

function fadeCF_spaceIN(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    CF_space.alpha = .5; 
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fadeCF_spaceOUT);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fadeCF_spaceOUT);      }

function fadeCF_spaceOUT(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    CF_space.alpha = 0; 
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fadeCF_spaceOUT);  }
```

Example illustration:

[image]

Comment: Could it be related to: [Flash AS3 - Drag and Drop multiple objects to one target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359919/flash-as3-drag-and-drop-multiple-objects-to-one-target)

Comment: I'm not sure, because i'm inclined to think I shouldn't have to use the target method, since the user can place objects randomly across the stage, no fixed targets. But maybe I'm too badly versed in using it.

Comment: But what about the approach with array used there. What if you will do something similar, and store all your players in array. Then after dragging one of the players you can calculate direction and distance it was dragged, and apply that to all other players in that array. (I think that's what you want to do, right?)

Comment: I see what you mean, and i tried to implement it but I came out with the same result - the master object would move, but not its slave
This is what I made of it:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grateful for your addition, and indeed it proved to be even more simple, too simple:

```
object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

function drag(evt:MouseEvent):void {
     addChild(MovieClip(evt.currentTarget));
     evt.currentTarget.startDrag();
}

function drop(evt:MouseEvent):void {
     stopDrag();
     object_space.x = object.x;
     object_space.y = object.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var CF_1:Array = [CF_mc, CF_space];  // instance names
for each(var CF1_MC:MovieClip in CF_1)
{
    CF1_MC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
    CF1_MC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
    CF1_MC.startX = CF1_MC.x;
    CF1_MC.startY = CF1_MC.y;
}

function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
}

function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling it's just a simple line of code but I'm too much of a noob I guess. I really need some help with this, could anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be 100% sure what you mean, but can you use ENTER_FRAME function instead of startDrag and stopDrag? Here's very minimal example of that, which you can also use with arrays of objects.

```
var xDifference:Number;
var yDifference:Number;
var dragging:Boolean;

draggableObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown);
draggableObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(evt:Event):void{
    if(dragging){
        draggableObject.x = mouseX;
        draggableObject.y = mouseY;

        secondaryObject.x = draggableObject.x + xDifference;
        secondaryObject.y = draggableObject.y + yDifference;
    }
}

function mDown(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    xDifference = secondaryObject.x - draggableObject.x;
    yDifference = secondaryObject.y - draggableObject.y;
    dragging = true;
}

function mUp(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    dragging = false;
}
```

Depending on the case you might also want to count difference between mouse cursor and draggableObject's registration point on MOUSE_DOWN to prevent draggableObject to jump to position where its center point is exactly on mouse position.